# is it possible to make a costum Status with slash commands in Discord.js v.14

Tags: discord.js

```
client.on('interactionCreate', (interaction) => {
 if (!interaction.isChatInputCommand()) return;

 if (interaction.commandName === 'status'){
      const stat = interaction.options.getString('status');
      client.user.setActivity({
        name: `${stat}`,
      });
      interaction.reply(`Spielstatus auf ${stat} geändert!`);
      console.log(`${stat}`)
    } else {
      interaction.reply('Fehler: Ungültiger Eingabewert.');
    }
 });
```

he sets the status every time to null

Pls tell me the Problem if you see it^^, im new in coding so it could be that my code is trash or something XD

Answer (score 1):

i solved it, i need an Option in the register-commands.js file

{
name: 'status',
description: "ändert den Botstatus an",
options: [
{
name: 'status',
type: 3,
description: 'Der neue Spielstatus des Bots',
required: true,
}
]
},